# Discover Torrent hosts on LAN stealing internet bandwidth

Tags: lan, network-discovery

My LAN is completely and constantly overwhelmed from some host in the network. The network is shared and I have no accesso to all its branches.

Ping to *WAN* addresses should be **15ms** usually but 90% of the time it is **100-500ms** (is a 5MB DSL connection).
I suspect someone is downloading over P2P (probably *BitTorrent*) continuously stealing all the bandwitdth and filling the *NAT* (so making all the other host's packets delayed).

Unfortunately:

- I don't know which host is the responsible
- I'm in a switched network; so I cannot run *Wireshark* to find the culprit
- I don't have access to the router and/or firewall; otherwise I would have set traffic filters, *QoS* or blocked torrent ports (or, at least, checked the logs).
- I had not luck in "human indagation" and have no other chances that relying on technical analyzing for finding that host.

#### How could I detect the computer that is causing all this connectivity slowdown on the LAN?

Probably the host is using a *VPN* to download: would it limit my chances to detect it?

I thought about:

- relying on *LDP* from BitTorrent protocol and listen for broadcast torrent packets (but I'm not having luck with it).
- sniff traffic on *LAN* (but, as mentioned, Wireshark is limited by the switch that delimit my network segment)
- use some tool for discovering *Torrent* clients (basing on broadcast packets, open ports, or other ways). But have no clue of which tools, or what I would need to do to achieve the analysis.

What methods would you suggest to discover it? What could be other paths to follow?

Comment: Hello @Kamafeather, and welcome to NE Stack Exchange.  Unfortunately, this question is off-topic.   Specifically in our [On-Topic](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) guidelines it lists:  "Off-topic: Users / Customers of Enterprise or Service Provider Networks"   You state: "I don't have access to the router and/or firewall".  I would recommend that you raise your concerns to the appropriate parties who do control your network.

Comment: You should get ahold of the person that has access to the routers and find out what make/model they are then research how to do application or flow recognition on that platform.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Unfortunately, questions by end users of a network not within their control are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. This is almost a model question why this is the case as without access to the network you won't be able to take any of the steps we recommend or provide us any information that we can use. We don't know if this is P2P related, only one device, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

**If it's your network that you are responsible for managing**, then you can setup a SPAN port and analyze using wireshark from there.  This is by far your best option.  If you don't have a switch capable of doing that, then there are other options.  I only give you these options in the case that a MSP or VOIP provider manages your router but you are an on site tech, which I have seen with some SMB clients.

You can use a hub or hardware passive ethernet tap(easy to make if you google it) between your switch uplink to the router, and plug in to that with your wireshark machine.  Another option is to do arp poisoning from a linux box to sniff a switched network.  The problem with these issues is that you can cause some pretty annoying network issues while you are analyzing the traffic.  You can also end up in some trouble with the law if it isn't your network and you shouldn't really be analyzing the traffic.  You won't be able to open the packets up if they are using encrypted bittorrent or going through a VPN, but you will see who's eating up all of your bandwidth.

Sorry, I didn't give explicit instructions on how to do everything, because I don't feel like writing a novel.  This post is already long.  You should be able to google the options that I've listed though.  Also, keep in mind that DSL will be asymmetrical, so 5m down and probably 768k up(if that), which doesn't take much to saturate.  15ms pings out to the internet is also VERY optimistic on your part, unless you pay a ton of money which I doubt since it's DSL.

Comment: The OP should check this link where similar questions has been asked before: http://serverfault.com/questions/147553/whats-the-best-way-to-monitor-internet-traffic-for-the-entire-office